# file system root without memory

Tags: partitioning, mount, root, memory-usage

I have recently encountered an issue with a pop-up window in my Ubuntu16.04 saying that I have little memory available in the "file system root"
The output of df -h command is:

```
myname@myPC:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           789M   79M  711M  10% /run
/dev/sdb1        19G   17G  1,1G  95% /
tmpfs           3,9G  165M  3,7G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop5       62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1081
/dev/loop8       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop10      66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop11      62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1026
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2128
/dev/loop7      338M  338M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/240
/dev/loop9       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
/dev/loop12      33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12883
/dev/loop0      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop4      304M  304M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-5-stable/16
/dev/loop2      165M  165M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/sda        917G   54G  817G   7% /mnt/AlmacenTB
/dev/sdb2       268G  248G  6,5G  98% /home
tmpfs           789M   84K  789M   1% /run/user/1520
/dev/loop13     256K  256K     0 100% /snap/acrordrdc/48
/dev/loop14     338M  338M     0 100% /snap/wine-platform-runtime/241
/dev/loop6      128K  128K     0 100% /snap/acrordrdc/53
```

The problem is that the PC has become very slow. Especially when opening multiple windows in Chrome.
Can anybody give a hand with this issue? what is that "loop" thing consuming 100% of its space? what is tmpfs?. I am a complete newby on all this...

Comment: The problem is that your disk is full... /dev/sdb1        19G   17G  1,1G  95% /. Your partition is too small.

Comment: Your /home is full too... /dev/sdb2       268G  248G  6,5G  98% /home

Comment: @heynnema Is there a way to list or see which files and folders take the most out of my memory in \home? Not all files in home, but the heavy ones?

Comment: The `Disk Usage Analyzer` is the tool to use.